# Nested loop with contourplot

Tags: plotting

The ContourPlot is applied 5 times with this code:

```
i = Range[1, 5]
j = Range[1, 5]
ContourPlot[x^2/i + y^2/j == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

However, I would like it to be applied 5 separate times for each 5 values of i (so 25 times in total). So a plot for (i=1 and j=1), (i=1 and j=2), (i=1 and j=3)... etc.

How do I create such a nested loop?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Show[ContourPlot[x^2/#1 + y^2/#2== 1,{x, -5, 5},{y, -5, 5}] & @@@ Tuples[Range@5, {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Using `Table`:

```
Table[ContourPlot[x^2/i + y^2/j == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], {i, 5}, {j, 5}]
```